# Pulling values from a piecewise function

Tags: python, for-loop, jupyter-notebook, enumerate, piecewise

I am trying to get values of a piecewise function of linearly spaced time points from an existing data set of times and positions. so if the dataset has time values of ts= 0,5,10,15 etc and I want them spaced at twant= 0,3,6,9 etc. the twant= 0,3 would have the xs value of 0, and 6,9 would have the xs value of 5, and so on and so forth. But I cannot get it to work, the code I have below would only give the correct values if ts =0,1,2,3,4 etc.
what can I do to do this?
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGzvo.png)

'''

```
ts = [0,5,10,15,20,25]

twant=[0,3,6,9,12,15]

xs= [1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000]

def getdata(tvalue, ts, xs):

    xvals=[]
    for i in tvalue:
        for j in xs:
            if j == i:
                xvals.append(xs[j])
return xvals

getdata(twant, ts, xs)  

Output --> (1000,4000)
```

Comment: I could not understand your question. It's possible to rewrite it?

Comment: @BarzanHayati i have included a diagram, i do not know how else to explain it other than i have a set of values (xs) with corresponding times(ts), but i want to get the values at a different set of linearly spaced times (twant), and that the x values of each ts are constant until the next ts, so if ts =0,5,10 and xs= 0,1,2, then the values of xs at t=1 or t=2 or t=3 are all 0 until t = 5, at which point xs becomes 1

Comment: I just confused, not anything more. But, I wish help you. You are new user here, So it's better write all thing that is need to solve this problem.